# CImg get_crop() returns wrong pixels / getting a subimage of CImg

Tags: c++, image-processing, cimg

I am trying to get a subimage of a CImg. As I understand the method get_crop() does what I need, but the subimages that I get do not contain the pixel values I expected them to have.

```
unsigned char* StringTextureGenerator::GetTexture(int &width, int &height)
{
    cil::CImg<unsigned char>* tmp = new cil::CImg<unsigned char>(512, 512, 1, 4);

    *tmp = _alphabet.get_crop(0, 0, 0, 0, 511, 511, 0, 3);

    width = tmp->width();
    height = tmp->height();
    return tmp->data();
}
```

The _alphabet CImg is 512x512x1x4 and contains an rgba image. For a test I am trying to get the whole the image x = 0 - 511, y = 0 - 511.
The result is this:

[image]

This is the expected outcome. I got the whole image as I loaded it from the file.

But when I try to get a sub-image, strange things do happen.

```
unsigned char* StringTextureGenerator::GetTexture(int &width, int &height)
{
    cil::CImg<unsigned char>* tmp = new cil::CImg<unsigned char>(256, 256, 1, 4);

    *tmp = _alphabet.get_crop(0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 3);

    width = tmp->width();
    height = tmp->height();
    return tmp->data();
}
```

Here I am getting the pixels x = 0 - 255, y = 0 - 255, which I expect to be the top left quarter of the picture.
The result is this:

[image: The result is this:]

As you can see I get the top left quarter of every 128x128 block. Which is not what I wanted.

Comment: The alphabet image you have provided is neither RGBA nor 512x512 - it is RGB and 674x554. Please provide the correct input image if you want help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I solved the problem by using another library and no longer have the image and code. So sadly I cannot verify that this was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is going on with your code, but this works fine on my machine. I am using **CImg** v169. I use this as a test image:

[image]

And run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;
int main() 
{
    CImg<unsigned char> alphabet = CImg<unsigned char>("alphabet.png");
    CImg<unsigned char> tmp = CImg<unsigned char>(512, 512, 1, 4);

    //tmp = alphabet.get_crop(0, 0, 0, 0, 511, 511, 0, 3);
    tmp = alphabet.get_crop(0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 3);
    tmp.save_png("result.png");
}
```

And get this, which looks correct to me:

[image]

I am compiling with options:

```
-Dcimg_use_png -lpng -lz
```